# Excel Macro: If the final characters of a cell is "something" then, cut them and paste them elsewhere

Tags: excel, if-statement, paste, vba

This is an extension of a previously asked question that was amazingly answered and made me think of how else I can simplify my sloppy code.

```
Dim i As Long, l As Long
l = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
For i = l To 1 Step -1
  If Right(Cells(i, 4).Value, 4) = " XX " Then 

   'do some stuff to cut and paste that ending to ColumnE'
    Cells(i, 5) = " XX "

   'i'm trying to do something like this to clear the final 4 characters.
    Right(Cells(i, 4).Value, 4).ClearContents

  End If
Next i
```

Comment: I'm confused by the question, but if you are simply trying to get the ending into column E, wouldn't you just do Cells(i,5) = " XX "? The 5 gives you column E, and for the action to ever take place, you know that the ending has to be " XX " (because that's what you're calling for in your IF/THEN), so just hard code that to column 5 (E).

Comment: @rryanp - I'm also trying to remove the " XX " ending from Cells(i,4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the left of the string, the number of chars is equal to the total length minus 4

```
Cells(i,4).Formula = Left(Cells(i, 4).Value, len(Cells(i, 4).Value)-4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or directly via two array IF tests

```
Sub Recut()
Dim lngCnt As Long
lngCnt = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
[e1].Resize(lngCnt, 1) = Application.Evaluate("=IF(RIGHT(D1:D" & lngCnt & ",4)="" XX "","" XX "","""")")
[d1].Resize(lngCnt, 1) = Application.Evaluate("=IF(RIGHT(D1:D" & lngCnt & ",4)="" XX "",LEFT(D1:D1000,LEN(D1:D" & lngCnt & ")-4),D1:D" & lngCnt & ")")
End Sub
```