# Excel Macro: If the characters " XX " are in the middle of a string then split the string at that point

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, split

I'm trying to divide a column into two columns based on finding a specific characters in the string.

Specifically, if ColumnA contains the string " XX " then, copy all before " XX " in ColumnD, and copy " XX " & everything after to ColumnF.

```
Sub splitit()
Dim i As Long, l As Long
l = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = l To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, celltxt, " XX ") Then
      Cells(i, 4).Value = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, Find(" XX ", Cells(i, 1).Value) - 1)
      Cells(i, 6).Value = " XX " & Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, Find(" XX ", Cells(i, 1).Value) + 1, Len(Cells(i, 1).Value))
    End if
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Haven't we already answered this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686052/excel-macro-if-the-final-characters-of-a-cell-is-something-then-cut-them-and/28687998#28687998 You already asked how to get the left side, then in the linked article you asked for the right side.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub splitit()
Dim i As Long, l As Long,
Dim x as variant
l = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = l To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, celltxt, "XX") <> 0 Then
      x = split(cells(i,1),"XX")
          cells(i,4) = x(0)
          cells(i,6) = " XX " & x(1)
    End if
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks...I get a type mismatch error however, on the InStr line.

Comment: Perhaps change it to this: If InStr(1,Cells(i, 1).text, " XX ")>0 Then